# Don't have access to Spring boot controller, but have access to index.html

Tags: spring, tomcat, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot project, what I deployed on remote server. When I call `http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/` - I can see an `index.html`, but when I call rest controller by url `http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/countries` - I have an error 404 whith

> Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

It's strangely, because when I start this project on my local machine, all working right. Project structure is:

[image: project structure]

Line from `catalina.out` file:

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-19] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Parse error in application web.xml file at [file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/proxynator/WEB-INF/web.

My controller:

```
@RestController
class MainController(val proxyRepo: ProxyRepo, val countryRepo: 
CountryRepo) {

@GetMapping("/countries")
fun findCountries(): List<Country> = countryRepo.findAll()

@GetMapping("/proxies")
@ResponseBody
fun findProxies(@RequestParam countryid: Int): List<Proxy> = 
proxyRepo.findAllByCountryid(countryid)
}
```

### UPD

I added configuration class on the root package

```
@Configuration
open class RestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    open fun mainController():MainController
            = MainController()
}
```

But it does not working. I don't understand, why I can see `index.html` by irl `http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/`, but can't get access to my controllers. When I package my project I have some files:
[image]

Any advice?

Comment: please provide the controller mapping

Comment: Updated me question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I was edit my Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
open class Application: SpringBootServletInitializer(){

    @Override
    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder?): 
    SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return super.configure(application)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

I was override configure method, and all is working!
Hope it will save time for anybody!

Answer (score 0):

your api access url is wrong  access using http://109.206.178.66:8080/countries this is the correct path for your rest mapping,  not http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/countries

Comment: I have the same problem. I use /proxynator/ because it's my application on remote server. On local server it's working like you wrote.

Comment: And You can try to do it, because it's open port, if You can see anything, except index.html text "Hello World" on link "http://109.206.178.66:8080/proxynator/", tell me, please.

Comment: what is you web xml configuration

Comment: I don't have it